# How can I reset a Thread every 10 minutes?

Tags: java, multithreading, loading, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am making a program that communicates data through a resource folder within a network. There are two "types" of this same program, a runner and a viewer. The runner saves data and the viewer loads data. I am using OOS and OIS to do this. The runner saves the data to the resource every few seconds, and the viewer loads the data from the folder every few seconds as well. After some time between 10-80 minutes (as I have found), I get an EOFException when using a shared network, but in the Eclipse IDE, it runs smoothly for an indefinite time.

I don't know why this is. The first thing I did was move the load function to a separate thread, but that didn't help. Then I tried resetting the Thread every 10 minutes, that didn't work either. Would this solution even theoretically work or is there another glaring error in my logic.

Please ask if you need any more information.

Code for loading data through resetting Thread:

```
LinkedList<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
Timer resetTimer = new Timer();
        resetTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    threads.clear();
                    threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Timer loadDataClock = new Timer();
                            loadDataClock.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        loadData();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        advancedStackTrace(e, 1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 0, 5000);
                        }
                    }));
                    threads.get(0).start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10 * 60 * 1000);
```

(This works by adding Threads to a linked list every 10 minutes and clearing the LinkedList every 10 minutes and replacing it with a new Thread)

Code for loading in saving data within a DataHandler class:

```
public static void save(Serializable data, String filename) throws IOException {
        haltLoad = true;
        try {
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(filename + "_fir")))) {    
                oos.writeObject(data);
                try {
                    Path source = Paths.get(filename + "_fir");
                    Path target = Paths.get(filename);
                    Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        haltLoad = false;
    }

    public static Object load(String filename) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (!haltLoad) {
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filename)))) {
                return ois.readObject();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            } 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

(As a note, the variable haltLoad prevents loading while the save method is being called)

Comment: Try using a ScheduledExecutorService   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Instead of trying to work around the problem by "resetting" the thread, ***fix the problem***. Do you know why you get an EOFException? Did you know you can catch the EOFException and make the thread reset itself if it gets one?

Comment: I bet that you get EOFException because you load the file while the runner is still saving it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, everyone. I was able to fix it using a different way. user253751 was correct, ultimately the problem was it was loading while saving. I fixed it by writing the OOS to a file and copying that file to a readable file for the loader. I also added a boolean that disabled load calls while the save method was being called.